# Joomla field type as star rating

Tags: form-fields-types, fields

Can some one suggest that in Standard form field types in joomla 3.5 - there are many options like text, editor, file, media, radio etc

But - i can not get in a star rating option
I mean i have a product page and want to display star rating in it

Like <`field name="Expert Rating" type="rating" label="Expert Rating" description="View of Expert" hint="pls assign stars to product"/>`

Is there a way to select field type as rating and if we select say 2 rating then the front end can load 2 stars against it and say if we load 4 star then front end can load 4 stars in it

Pls advise

Comment: Why are you using Joomla 3.5? Please update to 3.7

Comment: i mean sorry - using joomla 3.6 , as 3.7 had some issues as mentioned by akeeba backup - hence hold on to upgrade. In meanwhile - is there a solution to the query of the rating pls

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard form field type for star rating. However, you can decorate a standard form field look like star rating.

For example, the below jQuery library can generate star rating using standard HTML textbox field.

http://dobtco.github.io/starrr/

You can develop your own custom field if you want pure Joomla form field. See the documentation below.

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Comment: @Ruchika did that answer satisfy? If so, please award the green tick.  If you still require more support, please update your question and leave a comment under this answer to explain where you could still use some help.  All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.